# Dict issue: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python

**Problem**
I have this code:

```
def _score_sentences(tf_idf_matrix) -> dict:
      sentenceValue = {}

    for sent, f_table in tf_idf_matrix.items():
        total_score_per_sentence = 0

        count_words_in_sentence = len(f_table)
        for word, score in f_table.items():
            total_score_per_sentence += score

        sentenceValue[sent] = round(total_score_per_sentence / count_words_in_sentence, 3)

    return sentenceValue

sentence_scores = _score_sentences(tf_idf_matrix)
```

Basically, it's supposed to create a dictionary with sentences that each have a float score assigned to them (taken from `tf_idf_matrix`). It prints out something that looks like a dictionary, but when I run this bit of code:

```
top_scores = {}
for sent, score in sentence_scores.items():
    if f_table >= .4:
        top_scores[sent] = score

print(top_scores)
```

I get this error report:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-2220086aa6aa> in <module>
      1 top_scores = {}
      2 
----> 3 for sent, score in sentence_scores.items():
      4     if f_table >= .4:
      5         top_scores[sent] = score

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

**Partial Solution**

I've seen some other questions about this, suggesting to try using `ast.literal_eval()`. However, when I try

```
import ast

d = ast.literal_eval(sentence_scores)
top_scores = {}

for sent, score in d.items():
    if f_table >= .4:
        top_scores[sent] = score
print(top_scores)
```

I get this error report:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\users\...\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-51-3d124b40f0bb>", line 3, in <module>
    d = ast.literal_eval(sentence_scores)

  File "c:\users\...\lib\ast.py", line 59, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')

  File "c:\users\...\lib\ast.py", line 47, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,

  File "<unknown>", line 1
    P's grandfather
                  ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Sorry for the long question; I wanted to try to be as clear as possible in problem and my attempts to solve it. Basically, I'd like to know whether or not `sentence_scores` is a string. If it is, I'm wondering why `ast.literal_eval()` isn't working. If `sentence_scores` is a dictionary, I'd like to know why I'm getting that initial `AttributeError`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide dictionary tf_idf_matrix key/pair value to run the program.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Type checking ought to clear this up.  I don't have enough context to be able to figure out if your code is being used correctly, but add better type annotations to it:

```
from typing import Dict

def _score_sentences(tf_idf_matrix: Dict[str, Dict[str, float]]) -> Dict[str, float]:
    sentence_value: Dict[str, float] = {}

    for sent, f_table in tf_idf_matrix.items():
        total_score_per_sentence = 0.0

        count_words_in_sentence = len(f_table)
        for word, score in f_table.items():
            total_score_per_sentence += score

        sentence_value[sent] = round(total_score_per_sentence / count_words_in_sentence, 3)

    return sentence_value

sentence_scores = _score_sentences(tf_idf_matrix)
```

and then run `mypy` -- that'll tell you where the problem is.  My hunch is that something may be overwriting `sentence_scores` elsewhere in your code.